# Trying to install wxpython on Mac OSX

Tags: python, macos, wxpython

I am trying to install wxpython onto my Mac OSX 10.8.3. I download the disk images from their downloads page and mount it. When I try to install the package I get an error that saying that the package is damaged and can't be opened. Any suggestions on how I can fix this?

I have also tried opening the package through the terminal but no luck.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check the md5. also, this is off-topic. At least post the exact error code.

Comment: There is no error code, that is the error that I get. @Tadgh

Comment: Sounds like a corrupt download. Did you check the md5 sum, as suggested by Tadgh?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is a known issue: http://trac.wxwidgets.org/ticket/14523.

The wxPython installer was created with an ancient package building tool that is no longer support. The workaround is to install from the command line:

```
sudo installer -pkg /Volumes/wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-2.8.12.1-universal-py2.7/wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-universal-py2.7.pkg/ -target /
```

The output I got from this was:

```
installer: Package name is wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-universal-py2.7
installer: Installing at base path /
2013-06-27 00:23:38.157 installer[9373:5a03] Package /Volumes/wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-2.8.12.1-universal-py2.7/wxPython2.8-osx-unicode-universal-py2.7.pkg uses a deprecated pre-10.2 format (or uses a newer format but is invalid).
installer: The install was successful.
```

Answer (score 8):

Go to System preferences --> Security and privacy --> Allow applications downloaded from..select 'Anywhere'

Comment: I almost didn't try this because it didn't seem to match the "package is damaged " error message. But, in fact, it worked!

Comment: ... not in el-capitan. I almost.. woa!

Comment: Worked on OSX Yosemite also. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

An other way to install Wxpython:
Use brew* to install wxmac using the following command.

brew install --python wxmac --devel

once you install the wxmac create a symbolic link between the installed wx to the python library.

sudo ln -s /usr/local/Cellar/wxmac/2.9.4.0/lib/python2.7/site-packages/wx /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/wx

I Hope it will be helpful for future installers.

*if you do not have Brew installed prior, install it using the following command: ruby -e "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/go/install)"